# How to dock a footer menu to bottom in Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

How do I dock a footer menu to the bottom of the screen on Android and iPhone in Appcelerator Titanium? I want to display 3 icons on the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [Titanium.UI.View](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.View-object) and set bottom: 0 to get it to dock to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we use Ti.UI.Toolbar for this. Let see this example code:

```
var space = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.FLEXIBLE_SPACE
});

var buttonNextEnd = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: '>>'
});
var buttonNext1Page = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: '>'
});
var buttonPrevEnd = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: '<<'
});
var buttonPrev1Page = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: '<'
});

var toolbarNav = Titanium.UI.createToolbar({
    left : 0,
    bottom: 0,
    height : 40,
    width : 320,
    items: [buttonPrevEnd,space, buttonPrev1Page,space, buttonNext1Page, space,buttonNextEnd]
});

win.add(toolbarNav);
```

Comment: I didn't get toolbar to work in Android. The documentation indicates it is an iPhone only feature.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Titanium.UI.ToolBar](https://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.0/Titanium.UI.Toolbar) for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Appcelerator [Alloy Framework](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework)

The code in the XML view

```
<Alloy>
    <Window title="My Nice Title">
        ...   ...   ...
        ...   ...   ...
        <View class="footer-menu"></View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

The code in TSS

```
".footer-menu": {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: '100%',
    height: 40,
    bottom: 0
}
```

This will push the view to bottom. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Not using Alloy? It is similar in JS too.

```
// create window     
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    // if anything
});
// create view
var footer_menu = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: '100%',
    height: 40,
    bottom: 0
});
// add view to window
win.add(footer_menu);
```

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var footer = Ti.UI.createView({

    height:25
});

var footerButton = Ti.UI.createLabel({

    title:'Add Row',
    color:'#191',
    left:125,
    width:'auto',
    height:'auto'
});

footer.add(footerButton);
```

it works on android, but i still dont know why the button cant appear on iphone

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Toolbars aren't compatible for Android or Tablet.

If you want to set buttons to the bottom of the screen, create a View, set it at the bottom and then distribute the buttons with relative position, considering the screen width.

Here's an example:

```
    function FirstWindow() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        background : "black",
        height : "auto",
        width : "auto",
        layout : "vertical"
    });

    teste = Ti.UI.createView({
        left : 0,
        bottom : 0,
        opacity : .7,
        backgroundColor : "#3d3d3d",
        height : 55
    });


    var button1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
                title : "button 1",
        left : 0,
        width : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.3
    });
    var button2 = Ti.UI.createButton({
                title : "button 2",
        left : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.33,
        width : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.3
    });
    var button3 = Ti.UI.createButton({
                title : "button 3",
        left : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.66,
        width : Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * 0.3
    });
    view.add(button1);
    view.add(button2);
    view.add(button3);

        self.add(view);

    return self;
}

module.exports = FirstWindow;
```

Doing this... you are positioning the buttons in the View.

The first button ( button1 ) begins in "left: 0" and has a width of 30% of the View.
The second button ( button2 ) begins after the first button plus a space, and so on...

And the height of them is the same as the view's.